# Setting headers and footer ON or OFF by default while printing in Edge browser?

Tags: javascript, css, printing, microsoft-edge

I have searched a lot but didn't find any way to enable header and footer on every page of print by default in Edge browser.

On Chrome and IE header and footer is appearing by default but in Edge it is OFF by default. Is there any CSS property needs to be set for Edge browser to display header and footer by default on every page of print?

Here is the JS and CSS used to print the page:

```
private createIframe() {
        let oldFrame: any = document.getElementsByClassName('e-ngx-print-frame');
        if (oldFrame.length > 0) {
            oldFrame[0].parentNode.removeChild(oldFrame[0]);
        }
        try {
            let printIframe: any = document.createElement('iframe');
            document.body.appendChild(printIframe);
            printIframe.style.position = 'absolute';
            printIframe.style.border = '0';
            printIframe.style.width = '0';
            printIframe.style.height = '0';
            printIframe.style.left = '0';
            printIframe.style.top = '0';
            printIframe.style.zIndex = '-1';
            printIframe.className = 'e-ngx-print-frame';
            this.printWindow = printIframe.contentWindow;
            this.printDoc = printIframe.contentDocument ? printIframe.contentDocument : (printIframe.contentWindow ? printIframe.contentWindow.document : printIframe.document);
        }
        catch (e) {
            throw e + '. iframes may not be supported in this browser.';
        }

        if (!this.printWindow) {
            throw 'Cannot find window.';
        }

        if (!this.printDoc) {
            throw 'Cannot find document.';
        }
    }

    private getPrintWindow() {
        if (this.mode === this.modes.iframe) {
            this.createIframe();
        } else if (this.mode === this.modes.popup) {
            this.createPopup();
        }
    }

public print(printHTML?: any) {
        this.printHTML = printHTML ? printHTML : this.printHTML;
this.oldBtnText = this.btnText;
        this.btnText = 'Print';
        let timeoutId: number = window.setTimeout(() => {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            this.getPrintWindow();
            this.write();
            this.startPrint();
        }, 500);
    }

**CSS**:
 @media print 
    {
@page 
      {
        size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
       margin-top:0mm; /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
      }
}
```

Comment: hey welcome to SO please add your code and learn how to ask question

Comment: sorry !! added code now.